# How to get clang format to break in middle of arguments instead of after parenthesis?

Tags: c++, clang-format

I have a function definition that's pretty long, and it exceeds the line length limit:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL CJNITTMRenderer::Render(JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz, int jMouseEventCount, jintArray jMouseEvents)
{
}
```

I want clang-format to break it in the middle of arguments, after a comma, like so:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL CJNITTMRenderer::Render(JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz, int jMouseEventCount,
   jintArray jMouseEvents)
{
}
```

However, it instead breaks it like this:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL CJNITTMRenderer::Render(
   JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz, int jMouseEventCount, jintArray jMouseEvents)
{
}
```

I'll post my whole `.clang-format` below. I'm using version 6.0.1. What configuration should I change to get the desired formatting?

```
---
Language:        Cpp
# BasedOnStyle:  Mozilla
AccessModifierOffset: -3
AlignAfterOpenBracket: DontAlign
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: false
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: false
AlignEscapedNewlines: Left
AlignOperands: false
AlignTrailingComments: true
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: false
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: Inline
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: true
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: true
BinPackArguments: true
BinPackParameters: true
BraceWrapping:
  AfterClass:      true
  AfterControlStatement: true
  AfterEnum:       true
  AfterFunction:   true
  AfterNamespace:  true
  AfterObjCDeclaration: true
  AfterStruct:     true
  AfterUnion:      true
  AfterExternBlock: true
  BeforeCatch:     true
  BeforeElse:      true
  IndentBraces:    true
  SplitEmptyFunction: true
  SplitEmptyRecord: true
  SplitEmptyNamespace: true
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: None
BreakBeforeBraces: Allman
BreakBeforeInheritanceComma: false
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: true
BreakConstructorInitializers: BeforeComma
BreakAfterJavaFieldAnnotations: true
BreakStringLiterals: true
ColumnLimit:     100
CommentPragmas:  '^ IWYU pragma:'
CompactNamespaces: true
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: false
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 3
ContinuationIndentWidth: 3
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true
DerivePointerAlignment: false
DisableFormat:   false
FixNamespaceComments: true
ForEachMacros:
  - foreach
  - Q_FOREACH
  - BOOST_FOREACH
IncludeBlocks:   Preserve
IncludeCategories:
  - Regex:           '^"(llvm|llvm-c|clang|clang-c)/'
    Priority:        2
  - Regex:           '^(<|"(gtest|gmock|isl|json)/)'
    Priority:        3
  - Regex:           '.*'
    Priority:        1
IncludeIsMainRegex: '(Test)?$'
IndentCaseLabels: true
IndentPPDirectives: None
IndentWidth:     3
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: false
JavaScriptQuotes: Leave
JavaScriptWrapImports: true
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: false
MacroBlockBegin: ''
MacroBlockEnd:   ''
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
NamespaceIndentation: All
ObjCBlockIndentWidth: 3
ObjCSpaceAfterProperty: true
ObjCSpaceBeforeProtocolList: false
PenaltyBreakAssignment: 2
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 20
PenaltyBreakComment: 300
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 1
PenaltyBreakString: 1000
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 10
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 60
PointerAlignment: Left
RawStringFormats:
  - Delimiter:       pb
    Language:        TextProto
    BasedOnStyle:    google
ReflowComments:  true
SortIncludes:    true
SortUsingDeclarations: true
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: false
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: false
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 1
SpacesInAngles:  false
SpacesInContainerLiterals: false
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: false
SpacesInParentheses: false
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false
Standard:        Cpp11
TabWidth:        3
UseTab:          Never
...
```

Comment: With my `.clang-format` the arguments were broke after each comma. You check it [here](https://github.com/vjavs/Programming/blob/rework_calculator/.clang-format).

Comment: @ViniciusSa I looked at yours and I can't identify the specific settings that change that one behavior :-(

Comment: I don't think this is possible, `AlignAfterOpenBracket: DontAlign` and `BinPackParameters: true` are the important ones, but they will only break when you exceed the column limit (add more parameters to your declaration to exceed 100 chars and you will see). clang-format will always try to put parameters on a single line (when packing is enabled), it will only break when the parameter list (excluding function name and return type) is too long.